# Setting up selenium automation framework to run tests depending on cloud settings

Tags: selenium-webdriver, content-management-system, browser-automation

We have about 200 products having the same codebase. Apps are identified by appID and the content/features/feature configs are controlled via CMS. Like Feature 1 is enabled for AppID=1 and AppID=18 but not for AppID=53. Feature 1 can behave different in AppID=1 and AppID=18(again depending configs received from CMS).

We have automated tests based on AppID=1 and run them in CI environment. The picture is whenever we make a change e.g. for AppID=1 it affects to other apps as well so we want to test all apps to make sure nothing is broken.

Actually we can get the config from CMS for the AppID, but we don't know how should we proceed with it.

Can someone share his experience/solution if any?

Comment: Which CI tool you are using?

Comment: Jenkins on windows machine, as the product is web and most our users use it on windows machines with chrome browser